# Eclipse Button Run a program

Tags: java

I am new to coding. I am looking to make a Button.

What do I mean by button?

When you click on the button it will run a program .jar

thanks for help!

Maxime

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Play!");
    btnNewButton.setToolTipText("SpawnScape.jar");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Desktop.getDesktop();

            try {
                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Spawn.jar");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: just add full path of the jar like /opt/Spawn.jar and try

Comment: And what is your question? And what has that to do with eclipse? Hint: if you want reasonable answers, then image that the persons reading your questions are **not** you; and that we have **no** idea about all the details that you have been dealing with before writing up this lousy question.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work since you didn't specify the correct path to Spawn.jar
Place your jar file in C drive and try something like this if you are in windows,

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:\Spawn.jar");
```

Comment: Fixing the path works for the first 5 minutes; but as soon as you want to do something reasonable with the "overall application"; it will break apart.